# Sorting a ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> by a date range

Tags: android, json, listactivity, sorting

I am working on a Events app and need to be able to sort out my Events by the month that they happen.  I plan on using the Menu button to bring up the list of Months to choose from.  I tried using Collections.sort but Eclipse wouldn't allow it with the HashMap String, String.  How would I go about getting this class to only show Events in July?

public class Schedule extends ListActivity {

```
protected EditText searchText;
protected SQLiteDatabase db;
protected Cursor cursor;
protected TextView textView;
protected ImageView imageView;
protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> myList;
protected ImageLoader imageLoader;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.schedule);

    View layout = findViewById(R.id.gradiant);

    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(
            GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[] {
                    0xFF95B9C7, 0xFF06357A });
    gd.setCornerRadius(2f);

    layout.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);

    new GetEventsTask().execute("word");

}

public void featured(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Featured.class));
}

public void schedule(View view) {

}

public void venue(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Venues.class));
}

public void share(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Friends.class));
}

public void myravinia(View view) {
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Account.class));
}

protected class GetEventsTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> threadList;

    private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Schedule.this);

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        this.dialog.setCancelable(false);
        this.dialog.show();
    }



    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(
            String... params) {

        Log.v("Yup", "The thread is running");
        threadList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        JSONObject json = JSONfunctions
                .getJSONfromURL("my.jason.feed.url");

        try {


            JSONArray current = json.getJSONArray("d");

            for (int i = 0; i < current.length(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                JSONObject e = current.getJSONObject(i);

                map.put("id", String.valueOf(i));
                map.put("showid", "" + Html.fromHtml(e.getString("ShowID")));
                map.put("name", "" + Html.fromHtml(e.getString("Title")));
                map.put("showvenue", "" + e.getString("ShowVenue"));
                map.put("subtitle",
                        "" + Html.fromHtml(e.getString("SubTitle")));
                map.put("venueid", "" + e.getString("VenueID"));

                String showDate = e.getString("ShowDate");
                long epoch = Long.parseLong(showDate);
                Date showDatePresent = new Date(epoch * 1000);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMMM d");
                String dateOfShow = sdf.format(showDatePresent);
                map.put("showdate", "" + dateOfShow);

                String showStart = e.getString("ShowStart");
                long epoch2 = Long.parseLong(showStart);
                Date showTimePresent = new Date(epoch2 * 1000);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
                String timeOfShow = sdf2.format(showTimePresent);
                map.put("showstart", "" + timeOfShow);

                String showEnd = e.getString("ShowEnd");
                long epoch3 = Long.parseLong(showEnd);
                Date showEndPresent = new Date(epoch3 * 1000);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
                String endOfShow = sdf3.format(showEndPresent);
                map.put("showend", "" + endOfShow);

                String gatesOpen = e.getString("GatesOpen");
                long epoch4 = Long.parseLong(gatesOpen);
                Date gatesOpenPresent = new Date(epoch4 * 1000);
                SimpleDateFormat sdf4 = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "'Gates open: 'h:mm a");
                String gatesAreOpen = sdf4.format(gatesOpenPresent);
                map.put("gatesopen", "" + gatesAreOpen);

                map.put("aboutartist", "" + e.getString("AboutArtist"));
                map.put("program",
                        "" + Html.fromHtml(e.getString("Program")));
                map.put("programnotes",
                        "" + Html.fromHtml(e.getString("ProgramNotes")));
                map.put("pricing",
                        "" + Html.fromHtml(e.getString("Pricing")));
                map.put("featuring", "" + e.getString("Featuring"));
                map.put("parkdetails", "" + e.getString("ParkDetails"));
                map.put("starred", "" + e.getString("Starred"));

                map.put("image500", "" + e.getString("Image500"));

                map.put("image250", "" + e.getString("Image250"));

                map.put("aboutartist",
                        "" + Html.fromHtml(e.getString("AboutArtist")));
                threadList.add(map);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());

        }

        return threadList;          
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

        myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        myList = result;

        LazyAdapter adapter = new LazyAdapter(Schedule.this, myList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        final ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                HashMap<String, String> hashMap = myList.get(position);
                // hashMap.put("map", hashMap);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        ArtistDetails.class);
                intent.putExtra("map", hashMap);

                startActivity(intent);                  
            }

        });

        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
```

}

I know I left my code in there for functions not important to this task, but in an effort to be detailed...
Let me know if there are any other details I can provide to help solve this one.  Cheers!

My 2 adapters:

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());

}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.line_item, null);

    TextView name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.title); // title
    TextView showdate = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.showdate); // showdate
    TextView showstart = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.showstart); // showstart
    TextView showvenue = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.showvenue); // showstart
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image


    // Setting all values in listview
    name.setText(data.get(position).get("name"));
    showdate.setText(data.get(position).get("showdate"));
    showstart.setText(data.get(position).get("showstart"));
    showvenue.setText(data.get(position).get("showvenue"));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(data.get(position).get("image250"), thumb_image);
    return vi;
}
```

}

and

```
public class JSONfunctions {

public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url){
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jArray = null;

    //http post
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
    }

  //convert response to string
    try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }

    try{

        jArray = new JSONObject(result);            
    }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

    return jArray;
}
```

}

Comment: How to you currently populate `myList`? Also with the questions you have asked in the past, have you _never_ received an answer worthy of acceptance?

Comment: @Sam, I'm trying to get back and answer my open questions, though I have answered a couple of them.  Been busy and trying trying to get caught up.  myList is getting its info from .getJSONfromURL in my ArrayList.

Comment: Please post your code for building 'myList' from JSON data. And in the upper left of each answer box is a number and a check mark, you should check off the best answer for your previous questions. It lets the community now that the question is closed and gives the answerer credit for helping you. It good manners to upvote any answer that shows effort too.

Comment: I updated my code with two pieces.  I understand good manners and why an upvote shows respect.  But to be fair, since the answers given to me either are incomplete or dont relate, or were poorly worded, it takes me time to work through my issue. Sometimes so long I dont remember where the start of my solution began.

Comment: Also, @Sam, being a new user, I still can't upvote.  So please, try not to insinuate things you don't know about.