# Sorting a complete HashMap

Tags: java, android, sorting, collections, expandablelistview

I am trying to work with a seemingly complex HashMap object to pupulate my expandable Listview in android.

The generic parameters for my HashMap as as  shown below:

```
//HashMap<Map<YEAR,MONTH>,List<DAYS>>
HashMap<Map<Integer,Integer>,List<Integer>
```

I am using the Hash map to monitor day, month and year when an event took place. So assuming an event took place on 12th, 20th and 25th in May 2013, I would do something as this:

```
HashMap<Integer,Integer>,List<Integer>> events = new     HashMap<Integer,Integer>,List<Integer>();

HashMap<Integer,Integer> yearMonth = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
yearMonth.put(2013,5);
events.put(yearMonth,Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{12,20,25}));
```

I have created an adapter for my expandable list view and it displays fine as shown below. Now I want to be able to sort the above HashMap, first by Year and Month so that my listview will display events in 2014 at the top following by 2013, 2012 .... in that order.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Kindly go to this:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456847/sorting-a-arraylisthashmapstring-string-by-a-date-range?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456847/sorting-a-arraylisthashmapstring-string-by-a-date-range?rq=1)

Comment: You cannot use a HashMap like this.  In particular, using a mutable object (a Map) as the key to a Map will be disastrous.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just read "sort a hasmap". In the case you really want sort your data, a hashmap is definitely the wrong one.

Maybe you should think about using a linkedlist...

Comment: How do I represent the Years, Months and List<Days> mapping in a linked list? Is it possible? Thanks again.

Comment: A direct mapping is not possible, but you could do that via nested data structures. But if that is important for you, you should check if there is another dictionary implementation then hashmaps available (I am sure it is)

Answer (score 0):

Create your own class instead of the hashmap, and adjust the adapter to suit those objects.

Then you can implement your own sorting, by implementing *Comparable* and creating a `compareTo()` method in your class.

This gives you all the control you need. For example:

```
public class myEvent implements Serializable, Comparable<myEvent>
{
  private Integer day;
  private Integer month;
  private Integer year;

  public myEvent( Integer day, Integer month, Integer year, <your other data> )
  {
     // Save the stuff here
     this.day = day; 
     this.month = month; 
     this.year = year; 
  }

  // Create getDay(), getMonth(), getYear() methods for each parameter

  public int compareTo( myEvent another )
  {
     // Here, compare the two events year by year, month by month, and day by day
     if ( this.year.compareTo( another.getYear() ) == 0 )
     {
         if ( this.month.compareTo( another.getMonth() ) == 0 )
         {
             return this.day.compareTo( another.getDay() );
         } else {
             return this.month.compareTo( another.getMonth() );
         }
     } else {
         return this.year.compareTo( another.getYear() );
     }
  }

}
```

EDIT: When you want to sort a list of those *myEvent* objects, you can use the *Collection* api to make use of the *Comparable* implementation:

```
List<myEvent> allevents = new ArrayList<myEvent>();
// Add to the list
...
// Now sort it. 
Collections.sort( allevents );
```

Good luck.